# How to get distinct values from an arrays of different sizes?

Tags: c++

Q:

```
arr1[]={1,1,1,2,5,5,6,6,6,6,8,7,9}
```

Ans:

```
values[]={1,2,5,6,7,9}
```

Q:

```
arr1[]={1,1,1,2,5,5,6,6,6,6,8,7,9,101,1502,1502,1,9}
```

Ans:

```
values[]={1,2,5,6,7,9,101,1502}
```

here is what i tried but not working

```
   for(int i=0;i<(index-1);i++) { 
       if(data[i].age != data[i+1].age) { 
           c=new list; 
           c->value=data[i].age; 
           c->next=NULL; clas++; 
           if(age_head==NULL) { 
                p=c; age_head=c; 
           } 
           for(c=age_head;c!=NULL,c->next!=NULL;p=c,c=c->next) { 
               if(data[i].age!=c->value) 
                   found=false; 
               else 
                   found=true; 
           } 
           if((age_head!=NULL)&& (found=false)) { 
               p->next=c; c->next=NULL; 
           }
       }
   }
```

Comment: What do you suggest ? Did you try something ?

Comment: If this is homework, please tag it accordingly. Note that we don't do your homework for you - make some effort, show how far you got and where you are stuck, then we are happy to help you :-)

Comment: i tried n its not a home work

Comment: here is wat i tried but not wrkng
for(int i=0;i<(index-1);i++)
  {
   if(data[i].age != data[i+1].age)
   {
    c=new list;
    c->value=data[i].age;
    c->next=NULL;
    clas++;
    if(age_head==NULL)
    {
     p=c;
     age_head=c;
    }
    for(c=age_head;c!=NULL,c->next!=NULL;p=c,c=c->next)
    {
     if(data[i].age!=c->value)
      found=false;
     else
      found=true;
    }

    if((age_head!=NULL)&& (found=false))
    {
     p->next=c;
     c->next=NULL;
    }

Comment: @peter
dude its part ov ma office work n its been like 3 years since i wrote a cpp code so dats y i m a bit rusty on ds

Comment: I added the code to your main post - this way it is more readable. Please do so in the future, this is the SO way :-)

Comment: I removed the C tag, because of course, operator new is not part of C.

Answer (score 5):

This is not the most efficient, but it has some values:

1. It uses STL objects
2. It uses a cool little known template trick for knowing at compile time the size of your C-like arrays

...

```
int a[] = {1,1,1,2,5,5,6,6,6,6,8,7,9} ;
int b[] = {1,1,1,2,5,5,6,6,6,6,8,7,9,101,1502,1502,1,9} ;

// function setting the set values
template<size_t size>
void findDistinctValues(std::set<int> & p_values, int (&p_array)[size])
{
    // Code modified after Jacob's excellent comment
    p_values.clear() ;
    p_values.insert(p_array, p_array + size) ;

}

void foo()
{
    std::set<int> values ;

    findDistinctValues(values, a) ;
    // values now contain {1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}

    findDistinctValues(values, b) ;
    // values now contain {1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 101, 1502}
}
```

Another version could return the set, instead of taking it by reference. It would then be:

```
int a[] = {1,1,1,2,5,5,6,6,6,6,8,7,9} ;
int b[] = {1,1,1,2,5,5,6,6,6,6,8,7,9,101,1502,1502,1,9} ;

// function returning the set
template<size_t size>
std::set<int> findDistinctValues(int (&p_array)[size])
{
    // Code modified after Jacob's excellent comment
    return std::set<int>(p_array, p_array + size) ;
}

void foo()
{
    std::set<int> valuesOne = findDistinctValues(a) ;
    // valuesOne now contain {1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}

    std::set<int> valuesTwo = findDistinctValues(b) ;
    // valuesTwo now contain {1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 101, 1502}
}
```

Comment: Since you're clearing p_values anyway, why not just construct a new set from the p_array and assign it to p_values instead? Like this: p_values = std::set<int>( p_array, p_array + size ); Not sure if that shows up right, don't know how to do code in comments.

Comment: @Cedric H: I've learned it from Microsoft's example for strcpy_s, which is quite great (look at the C++ overload): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/td1esda9.aspx

Comment: @Jacob: You're SO right. I was too concentrated on the template to remember I should use the iterator constructor and insertion functions for the set object. I modified the code to take account of your comment.

Answer (score 4):

The first thing I spot in your code is

```
if((age_head!=NULL)&& (found=false)) {
```

you use assignment (=) instead of equality (==). The expression should be

```
if((age_head!=NULL)&& (found==false)) {
```

Then, in this loop

```
       for(c=age_head;c!=NULL,c->next!=NULL;p=c,c=c->next) {
```

you are looking for a value in the list. However, in its current form, when the loop terminates, `found` will show whether the *last* element in the list equals to `c->value`. You need to check for `found` in the loop condition (and you need to AND the expressions instead of listing them separated by comma!):

```
       for(c=age_head, found = false; !found && c!=NULL && c->next!=NULL; ...) {
```

The result of the comma operator is the result of the last subexpression inside - this is definitely not what you want. Moreover, with comma all subexpressions are evaluated, which results in dereferencing a null pointer if `c == NULL` - whereas the `&&` operator is evaluated lazily, thus `c->next!=NULL` is evaluated only if `c != NULL`.

The next thing is that you need to search for the value in the list *before* you add it to the list! Also note that you are trying to check for two different things: that the actual `data` element is different from the next one, and that its value is not yet added to the list. The second condition is stronger - it will always work, while the first only works if the input data is ordered. So you can omit the first check altogether. The result of all the above, plus some more simplifications and clarifications, is

```
for(int i=0;i<index;i++) { 
   for(list* c=age_head, found=false; !found&&c&&c->next; p=c,c=c->next) { 
       if(data[i].age==c->value) 
           found=true; 
   } 
   if(!found) { 
       list* newc=new list;
       newc->value=data[i].age; 
       newc->next=NULL;
       clas++;
       if(age_head==NULL) {
           p=newc; age_head=newc;
       } else {
           p->next=newc; newc->next=NULL;
       }
   }
}
```

I still don't guarantee that your linked list handling logic is right though :-) In its current form, your code is hard to understand, because the different logical steps are not separated. With a bit of refactoring, the code could look a lot clearer, e.g.

```
for(int i=0;i<index;i++) { 
   if(!foundInList(data[i].age)) {
       addToList(data[i].age);
   }
}
```

Of course the simplest and most efficient would be using STL containers/algorithms instead, as shown in other answers. But I think there is much more educational value in improving your first attempt :-)

Comment: if((age_head!=NULL)&& (found==false)) {
 done but still not wrkng sumthngs wrong

Answer (score 2):

If the output need not to be sorted, you can use a Hashtable.

E.g. something like this:

```
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
#define foreach BOOST_FOREACH
#include <boost/unordered_set.hpp>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
using namespace boost;

int main() {
  int arr1[]={1,1,1,2,5,5,6,6,6,6,8,7,9};
  size_t n = sizeof(arr1)/sizeof(int);
  unordered_set<int> h;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    h.insert(arr1[i]);
  vector<int> values;
  foreach(int a, h)
    values.push_back(a);
  return 0;
}
```

The runtime is then in O(n).

An alternative to that is sorting the array and then to eliminate neighboring identical elements (advantage only STL is needed). But then the runtime is in O(n log n):

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  int arr1[]={1,1,1,2,5,5,6,6,6,6,8,7,9};
  size_t n = sizeof(arr1)/sizeof(int);

  sort(arr1, arr1+n);
  int *end = unique(arr1, arr1+n);

  vector<int> values(arr1, end);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Easily done using STL.

```
int array[] = { 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 4, 5, 4, 4, 1, 1, 2 };
int nElements = sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]);
std::sort(&array[0], &array[nElements]);
int newSize = std::unique(&array[0], &array[nElements]) - &array[0];
```

Comment: or instead of `&array[0], &array[nElements]` you can say `array, array + nElements`.

Comment: std::unique does not return the new size of the array, it returns the end address ...

Answer (score 0):

first you need to sort the array and than do something like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < size -1; i++)
{
     if(array[i]!=array[i+1])
       unique++;

       // store it wherever you want to.
       stored.push(array[i]);
}
```

Comment: i dunn wanna coun values i wanna store dem

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int
main ()
{
  int array[] = { 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 4, 5, 4, 4, 1, 1, 2 };
  std::vector < int >values;
  values.push_back (array[0]);
  for (int i = 1; i < sizeof (array) / sizeof (int); ++i)
    {
      std::vector < int >::iterator it =
        std::find (values.begin (), values.end (), array[i]);
      if (it == values.end ())
        values.push_back (array[i]);
    }

  std::cout << "Result:" << std::endl;
  for (int i = 0; i < values.size (); i++)
    std::cout << values[i] << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Note that the runtime of this is in O(n^2), i.e. the runtime of the program grows quadratically with the size of the array. Using (at least) sort + unique is in O(n log n) and is less code.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a duplicate of [Removing duplicates in an array while preserving the order in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3598811/removing-duplicates-in-an-array-while-preserving-the-order-in-c-closed)
While the wording of the question is different, the result is the same.

Comment: Which is in itself a duplicate... hm, I don't get the duplicate mechanism on stackoverflow ;)

Answer (score 0):

Based on above ideas/codes, I am able to accomplish my job on finding distinct values in C++ array. Thanks every one who replied on this thread.

```
#include <set>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
// function setting the set values
template<size_t size>
void findDistinctValues(std::set<int> & p_values,int (&p_array)[size])
{
    // Code modified after Jacob's excellent comment
    p_values.clear() ;
    p_values.insert(p_array, p_array + size) ;

}

void findDistinctValues2( int arr[],int size)
{
  std::set<int> values_1 ;
  std::set<int>::iterator it_1;
  values_1.clear();
  values_1.insert(arr,arr+size);
  for (it_1=values_1.begin(); it_1!=values_1.end(); ++it_1)
    std::cout << ' ' << *it_1<<endl;

}

int main()
{
  int arr[] = {1,6100,4,94,93,-6,2,4,4,5,5,2500,5,4,5,2,3,6,1,15,16,0,0,99,0,0,34,99,6100,2500};
  std::set<int> values ;
  std::set<int>::iterator it;

  int arr_size = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int); 
  printf("Total no of array variables: %d\n",arr_size);
  printf("Output from findDistinctValues (function 1)\n ");
  findDistinctValues(values, arr) ;
  for (it=values.begin(); it!=values.end(); ++it)
    std::cout << ' ' << *it<<endl;
  std::cout<<endl;    
  std::cout<<values.size()<<endl; //find the size of distict values

  printf("Output from findDistinctValues (function 2) \n "); 
  findDistinctValues2(arr,arr_size);

  getchar();
  return 0;
}
```