# List with unique elements

Tags: c++, collections

I need a container, where:

- when I add a new element that does not exist yet, it is added to the top of the list
- when I add an element that already exists, it is not added and I I get its index in the list
- once the element is inserted, it always has the same index and it can be accessed using this index

`std::set` alone is insufficient, because I cannot access the elements with `[index]`. `std::list` neither, because it does not store unique only elements.

I used a mixed solution with `list` and `map` but maybe there is some standard, generic template for that?

I don't want to use boost. Invoking `list::unique` after every insertion is no solution.

Comment: How about rolling your own? Have you tried? Sounds like a very thin wrapper over `list`...

Comment: @Soohjun: Implementing this with `list` would not be good; the initial collision detection would be O(n), as would looking things up by index.

Comment: list *and* map, if you frequently add existing elements.

Comment: Yup, I have my own class, that maintains list together with map (for uniqueness of the items) but I thought that maybe I missed some standard template for that

Comment: I know you don't want to use Boost, but this is effectively what Boost.bimap does!

Comment: **Why** is using `list::unique` no solution, if its done automatically?

Comment: @macs: suppose it's slow (although I have not checked)

Comment: @JakubM. have you seen this similar question: [How to make elements of vector unique?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453333/how-to-make-elements-of-vector-unique-remove-non-adjacent-duplicates)?

Comment: @macs: `list::unique` removes **consecutive** duplicates.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth right, i forgot, so it's no solution at all. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: List and set sounds best.  Why use a map storing both key and value when key and value are the same?

Comment: @user1158692: There are effectively 2 keys (the element itself, and the associated integer index that's its assigned).

Comment: @moooeeeep: pass `[index]`, not `[key]`

Comment: @JakubM.: "maybe there is some standard, generic template" - there's nothing standard, but Boost.MultiIndex is close to a standard. Obviously that's not an option if you don't want to use Boost for some reason; and for simple cases like yours it's probably easier to roll your own.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using just a `std::list` (or `std::vector`, for that matter),
you're not going to get around a linear search if you don't want to
avoid duplicated, but you want to keep the original order.  A simple
`std::vector` based solution might be:

```
int
createIndex( std::vector<T>& references, T const& newValue )
{
    int results = std::find( references.begin(), references.end(), newValue )
                                    - references.begin();
    if ( results == references.size() ) {
        references.push_back( newValue );
    }
    return results;
}
```

Alternatively, you can use `std::map`:

```
int
createIndex( std::map<T, int>& references, T const& newValue )
{
    st::map<T, int>::iterator results = references.find( newValue );
    if ( results == references.end() ) {
        results = references.insert(
                    std::make_pair( newValue, references.size() ) ).first;
    }
    return results->second;
}
```

(This supposes that `T` supports `<`.  If not, you'll have to establish
an ordering critera.  Or use `unordered_map` and define a hash code for
it.)