# How to remove duplicates and keep only unique pointers in list?

Tags: c++, stl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make elements of vector unique? (remove non adjacent duplicates)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453333/how-to-make-elements-of-vector-unique-remove-non-adjacent-duplicates)
>   [Remove duplicates from a list<int>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4885676/remove-duplicates-from-a-listint)

I have list of pointers like

```
std::list<Person*> persons;
```

and there is duplicates in this list during filling. How to remove duplicates and stay only unique pointers in list ?

Comment: Maybe you've chosen the wrong data structure? Consider switching to `std::set`.

Comment: Do you want to preserve the relative order of the elements?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you can change the order of the elements, then first sort the list with [list::sort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/sort), then remove the duplicates with [list::unique](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/unique).

```
std::less<Person*> cmp;
persons.sort(cmp);
persons.unique(cmp);
```

On the other hand, you could use an [std::set](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set). It's elements are unique, ordered, and the [insert](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/insert) method fails if an element is already present in the set.

Bear in mind that the time complexity of insertion of single elements is logarithmic, whereas adding elements to the front or back of a list is constant time. On the other hand, `std::list::sort` is `N*log(N)`, and `std::unique` is linear. So if you intent to perform these duplicate removals frequently, you are better off with using an `std::set` in the first place. Also note that in C++11 there is [std::unordered_set](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set), which has element uniqueness and average constant complexity for insertions and removals.

Comment: A shame `sort` is not returning `list&`...

Comment: The insert time doesn't make much of a difference once you do an `O(N log N)` sort anyway.

Comment: If you're going to call `sort()` and `unique()` after every `insert`, a `set` `insert` would be faster. Possibly _much_ faster.

Comment: @Dave calling `sort()` and `unique()` after every insert would be pretty crazy. But I will add a few words on the time complexity of those methods.

Comment: I guess you meant *constant* complexity instead of *linear* in your sentence about `std::unordered_set`.

Comment: @ChristianRau yes, of course. Thanks for paying attention to the details!

Comment: How does sorting a list of pointers work? You can't use < or > to compare arbitrary pointers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4909766/is-it-unspecified-behavior-to-compare-pointers-to-different-arrays-for-equality

Comment: @BrianGordon very good point. I have modified the code in my answer to use `std::less<Person*>`, which should yield an adequate ordering.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't care about insertion order use a `set` instead of a `list`. There can only be unique elements in it and it will do the sorting others are recommending automatically.

If you do care about insertion order do something like this:

```
auto i = std::find(persons.begin(), persons.end(), pPerson);
if(i != persons.end())
    persons.erase(i);

persons.insert(pPerson);
```

(I didn't compile that)

Answer (score 1):

sort the list according to the address they are pointing at. the remove duplicates with a simple loop.